# NestedClass test failing, because Spring-Data-Mongo-Reactive is closing MongoDb connection (state should be: server session pool is open)

Tags: spring-webflux, junit5, inner-classes, spring-data-mongodb-reactive, reactive-mongo-java

### 1) Problem Description:

- I am using a Spring-Data-Mongo-Reactive, Testcontainers and JUnit 05;
- I have a Test-Class with simple-test and ‘Nested-Test-Class’(which has a simple test, as well);
- When, JUnit tests the NestedClass, the MongoDb Connection is closed, and the test 'Test's NestedClass' fail;

My Goal is:

- Keep the Reactive-MongoDB-Connection opened, in order to test, the ‘Nested-Test-Class’;

Below is the code for the above situation:

#### 1.1) Code:

**Current working status:** not working;

**Current behaviour:**

- The Reactive-MongoDB connection  is closing, when the ‘Nested-Test-Class’ is being tested, even though the first test is tested normally. .

```java
@Import(ServiceCrudRepoCfg.class)
@TestcontainerAnn
@TestsMongoConfigAnn
@TestsGlobalAnn
public class Lab {

  final private String enabledTest = "true";

  @Autowired
  IService serviceCrudRepo;


  @Test
  @DisplayName("Save")
  @EnabledIf(expression = enabledTest, loadContext = true)
  public void save() {
    Person localPerson = personWithIdAndName().create();

    StepVerifier
         .create(serviceCrudRepo.save(localPerson))
         .expectSubscription()
         .expectNext(localPerson)
         .verifyComplete();
  }


  @Nested
  @DisplayName("Nested Class")
  @Execution(SAME_THREAD)
  class NestedClass {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("findAll")
    @EnabledIf(expression = enabledTest, loadContext = true)
    public void findAll() {

      StepVerifier
           .create(serviceCrudRepo.findAll()
                                  .log())
           .expectSubscription()
           .expectNextCount(1L)
           .verifyComplete();
    }
  }
}
```

---

### 2) Current Problematic Log / Error:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNextCount(1)" failed (expected: count = 1; actual: counted = 0; signal: onError(org.springframework.data.mongodb.ClientSessionException: state should be: server session pool is open; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: server session pool is open))

### Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: server session pool is open

### 3) Question:

- How Can I Keep the Reactive-MongoDB-Connection opened, in order to test the ‘Nested-Test-Class’ as well?

---

*Thanks a lot for any help*

Comment: do you have any solution for that?